# Typescript dual sync / async return type

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise, overloading, typing

The following typescript code has the right "external" signature but the two `return` statements return an error ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=40#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVyQZ0xQHMAeAMQBo4AlOUGYFAE3zgDcJNm4AfOAApQIAW0z5gpTtwB8MgBQAoOBwCGAGyTAAXHCrK4RTDF3z2GrbvIBKOAF4ZtRdd10GTVoOFiJUrs0cAfi9RcUlyRys4AG8DNBx8eCh7QxRjMwtgawNMBDh5ZLsivBZgBCJgZlsoYBgkKFxzTWADGrqGuCgAOhgACyZ5eVsHNWbsgF8gA)).

```
export function using<F, R = void | Promise<void>>(
  value: F,
  init: (value: F) => R
): R extends Promise<void> ? Promise<F> : F {
  const r = init(value)
  if (r === undefined) return value
  return r.then(() => value)
}
```

A simple fix, as suggested by [known-as-bmf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63262942/356537), is to use function overloading as such:

```
export function using<F>(value: F, init: (value: F) => Promise<void>): Promise<F>
export function using<F>(value: F, init: (value: F) => void): F
export function using<F>(value: F, init: (value: F) => void | Promise<void>): F | Promise<F> {
  const r = init(value)
  if (r === undefined) return value
  return r.then(() => value)
}
```

But then you kinda loose the strong typing check in the function implementation, for example, the following is invalid but does not return any compilation error:

```
export function using<F>(value: F, init: (value: F) => Promise<void>): Promise<F>
export function using<F>(value: F, init: (value: F) => void): F
export function using<F>(value: F, init: (value: F) => void | Promise<void>): F | Promise<F> {
  const r = init(value)
  if (r === undefined) return Promise.resolve(value)
  return r.then(() => value)
}
```

Is there a way to make the first piece of code working all while keeping a strong type validation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to expose multiple signatures for the same function.

Example code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVyQZ0xQHMAeAMQD4AKANwEMAbJYALjnIBo4jMZ26TFu3IBKOAF5KcAApQIAW0z5gpWhEwATSqPZzFy1VQDcAKFCRYiVBmy4CRMlUHM2Hbr35wXwjuKlw6lq6HGYW0PDI6Fg4eIQkFDSmcIFCblzJPCh8AgyuIv7SQZpwAD6y8koqahrapiHkZRUG1VRwAN6ZaDj48FCSWXw+wKKZmAje-RLTeCiawAhEwJriUMAwSFC4eSyZaxtbcFAAdDAAFsAo1NSFqa6jAL6mpkA)

Depending on how you call `using`, it will return `F` or `Promise<F>`.

Example with usage [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVyQZ0xQHMAeAMQD4AKANwEMAbJYALjnIBo4jMZ26TFu3IBKOAF5KcAApQIAW0z5gpWhEwATSqPZzFy1VQDcAKFCRYiVBmy4CRMlUHM2Hbr35wXwjuKlw6lq6HGYW0PDI6Fg4eIQkFDSmcIFCblzJPCh8AgyuIv7SQZpwAD6y8koqahrapiHkZRUG1VRwAN6ZaDj48FCSWXw+wKKZmAje-RLTeCiawAhEwJriUMAwSFC4eSyZaxtbcFAAdDAAFsAo1NSFqa6jAL6mpkQwwFAI9GjAcADKisAACoATzAP06KRgoLcvSgjjMT1M3RQvTuvn+CiB0IG7TgULB7AA5PgAedHIS4A8zKYAPQ0uD0Hj4OAQCb4n4YrFgpE9eCMiRxRzDbjDW64h6iMx0uAAIyZLLZ2P0VVUnJBYMoPJR8DlAocJGF3h2I0k0mVhmOaxJjFowBukqAA)

Comment: This is what I ended up with. I was wondering if it was possible to do it without function overload...